# Using List to define a string as a list of characters and write a recursive function to return the length of the string

Tags: list, common-lisp

***Task***: Using List to define a **string as a list of characters** and write a recursive function to return the length of the string.

I wrote the code for this assignment but it just doesn't work.

Following is my code:

```
(defun stringlength  (string)
 ;;  "Compute the length of str."

   (if (string= string nil )   0

       (+ 1 (stringlength(subseq string 1)))))
```

and in the command line I typed:

```
cl-user(32): (stringlength "aaa")
```

it gave me the error:

```
Stack overflow (signal 1000)
  [condition type: synchronous-operating-system-signal]
```

Could anybody can help me with this? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun stringlength (string)
  (if (string= string nil)
      0
      (+ 1 (stringlength (subseq string 1)))))
```

You should document or test that the function expects a list of characters. Otherwise it is confusing, since STRING and string operations are built into Lisp and strings are not lists.

You already are confused by it ;-). `STRING=` is a function from Lisp which is defined for the built-in type `STRING`. You can't use it, because your task is to implement an operation over a list of characters. Also `SUBSEQ` is the wrong function.

To replace `STRING=` you need a function which tests whether something is the empty list or not.

To replace `SUBSEQ` you need a function which returns the list with the head element removed.

```
(stringlength "aaa")
```

Above then is also wrong. You need to call it with a list of characters, not a built-in string type. See your task. See the function `LIST` and see also how characters in Lisp are written.